# How to write a range so that one of the values is left open to user input

Tags: python, range, jython, jes

I would like to write a function for range where you enter a value when you are calling the function.

```
def randomRange():
    for num in range(0, ())
        print num
```

I would like the user to call the function like this "randomizeRange()"

And then I would like them to enter an integer to represent the maximum value in the range. I'm trying to get a better understanding of how to use the range function.

Comment: Also useful for understanding the range function are docs and tutorials, check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range , http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/, etc. Google 'python range'

Answer (score 3):

You need to prompt the user for input using the `input()` or `raw_input()` methods and then convert this to an `int()`

Python 2:

```
def randomRange():
    for it in range(int(raw_input("How many loops?: "))):
        print it
```

Python 3:

```
def randomRange():
    for it in range(int(input("How many loops?: "))):
        print(it)
```

Example >input and >>output:

```
>>How many loops?:
> 2
>> 0
>> 1
```

Comment: I agree that `input` is appropriate, but only in Python 3. the OP's code uses unparenthesized print, so he must be on Python 2.7 or lower, in which case he ought to use `raw_input` instead.

Comment: It looks like the OP is using Python 2, so `raw_input` should be used.

Comment: Updated the answer